# what information can be accessed with just the bank account number?

Tags: privacy

one of my friends wants to deposit money into my other friends bank account.  obviously she needs the bank account number to do this. Can she access any other information in with just the bank account number, like the balance or anything?  Also does online or in-person deposit make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

using Bank account number alone will not let you directly reach any thing , but on some banks it is used as  username for online banking , or it will be asked by customer service person as layer of authentication, or it can be used for social engineering and be part of information gathering

Comment: "but on some banks it is used as username for online banking".  Seriously ?

Comment: Yes, he is right. For example Lloyd does that. But why is it so bad (as long as no one knows the PIN and the password)?

Comment: @xkcd Mostly because rather than needing to determine your username, PIN and password they now just need to determine your PIN and password. Still difficult, certainly, but there's no real reason to make identifying any of those pieces of information necessary to access your account a trivial matter.